# Are static variables with [ThreadStatic] attribute shared between AppDomains

Tags: c#

I have a variable named as [ThreadStatic] , will it shared across 2 app domains?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Effectively types in different `AppDomains` are completely separate types. The static variables are unrelated to each other, whether or not `[ThreadStatic]` is applied.